# Creating n-dimensional mathematical vector classes through inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, vectors

Right now I have no knowledge of templates, but I just finished learning about inheritance, and wanted to apply it to a `Vector3` class that I had already created. My thoughts were that vectors of different dimensions share some common operations, and so it should be possible to apply an inheritance hierarchy to this.

Ultimately I might want a program that can operate with vectors without knowing their dimension. As a result, all vectors inherit from an abstract base class `Vector` which contains the most general operations of vectors for all dimensions, such as `normalise()`, `get_length()` a `bool` conversion and `<<` `>>` operators.

I've included just the header because I'm really concerned only with making sure my inheritance structure is adequate. The function definitions would take up a lot of room, and I don't think they are too important (although let me know if they are necessary).

`Vector.h`

```
#ifndef MATHSVectors
#define MATHSVectors

#include <iostream>
#include <utility> //pair

class Vector{ //abstract base class but we do expect users, so virtual functions are public
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Vector&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Vector&);
protected: //needed by derived classes
    Vector() { }
    Vector(const Vector&) = default;
    Vector(Vector&&) = default;
    Vector& operator=(const Vector&) = default;
    Vector& operator=(Vector&&) = default;
public:
    static const double pi;
    virtual double get_length() const = 0;
    virtual Vector& normalise() = 0;
    virtual explicit operator bool() const = 0;
    virtual ~Vector() { } //needed if we dynamically allocate
private: //used for operator<< and operator>>
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const = 0;
    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream&) = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Vector&);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Vector&);







class Vector2 : public Vector {
    friend bool operator==(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
    friend bool operator!=(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
    friend Vector2 operator+(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
    friend Vector2 operator-(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
    friend Vector2 operator*(const Vector2&, double);
    friend Vector2 operator*(double, const Vector2&);
    friend Vector2 operator/(const Vector2&, double);
    friend double dot_product(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
public:

    Vector2() = default;
    Vector2(double a, double b): x(a), y(b) { }

    explicit operator bool() const override;

    Vector2& operator+=(const Vector2&);
    Vector2& operator-=(const Vector2&);
    Vector2& operator*=(double);
    Vector2& operator/=(double);

    double get_length() const override;
    Vector2& normalise() override;
    Vector2& rotateXY(double); //radians

    Vector2& setX(double a) { x = a; return *this;}
    Vector2& setY(double b) { y = b; return *this;}

    double getX() const { return x;}
    double getY() const { return y;}

private:
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const override;
    std::istream& read(std::istream&) override;
    std::pair<double, double> rotate(double, double, double);
    double x = 0, y = 0;

};

bool operator==(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
bool operator!=(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
Vector2 operator+(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
Vector2 operator-(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);
Vector2 operator*(const Vector2&, double);
Vector2 operator*(double, const Vector2&);
Vector2 operator/(const Vector2&, double);
double dot_product(const Vector2&, const Vector2&);








class Vector3 : public Vector {
    friend bool operator==(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
    friend bool operator!=(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
    friend Vector3 operator+(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
    friend Vector3 operator-(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
    friend Vector3 operator*(const Vector3&, double);
    friend Vector3 operator*(double, const Vector3&);
    friend Vector3 operator/(const Vector3&, double);
    friend double dot_product(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
    friend Vector3 cross_product(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
public:

    Vector3() = default;
    Vector3(double a, double b, double c): x(a), y(b), z(c) { }

    explicit operator bool() const override;

    Vector3& operator+=(const Vector3&);
    Vector3& operator-=(const Vector3&);
    Vector3& operator*=(double);
    Vector3& operator/=(double);

    double get_length() const override;
    Vector3& normalise() override;
    Vector3& rotateXY(double); //radians
    Vector3& rotateXZ(double);
    Vector3& rotateYZ(double);

    Vector3& setX(double a) { x = a; return *this;}
    Vector3& setY(double b) { y = b; return *this;}
    Vector3& setZ(double c) { z = c; return *this;}

    double getX() const { return x;}
    double getY() const { return y;}
    double getZ() const { return z;}

private:
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const override;
    std::istream& read(std::istream&) override;
    std::pair<double, double> rotate(double, double, double);
    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

};

bool operator==(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
bool operator!=(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
Vector3 operator+(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
Vector3 operator-(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
Vector3 operator*(const Vector3&, double);
Vector3 operator*(double, const Vector3&);
Vector3 operator/(const Vector3&, double);
double dot_product(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);
Vector3 cross_product(const Vector3&, const Vector3&);


#endif // Vector3
```

The one thing I'm concerned with is there might be a lot of redundancy in function definitions - e.g. of defining `getX()` or `getY()` separately in every class of every dimension. An idea might be to define `Vector` and then inherit `Vector2` from that, and inherit `Vector3` from `Vector2`, and so on, so that I have `Vector(N+1)` inheriting from `Vector(N)`.

What I would be concerned with if using this method is that it reflects an odd relationship. Why would a `Vector3` be used in place of a `Vector2`? - It would also mean I could compare, or add, a `Vector3` to a `Vector2` (through run-time binding) and expect a return value of a `Vector2`. I am not sure, to be consistent mathematically, whether I would want that.

One last note is that, since I want to refactor the most general operations of a vector in to the `Vector` class, I thought it would make sense to refactor arithmetic operators in to the `Vector` class. That left me with the issue (again) that I could add Vectors of different dimensions through derived-to-base conversions. The plain arithmetic operators would also return `Vector` objects, rather than references, so there could be no consistent virtuality.

I'm sure that once I learn about templates there might be an easier way to generalise a `Vector` function to `n` dimensions, but for now, is this looking okay?

Answer (score 6):

This is a problem made for templates and using inheritance here is a bad idea. Instead of trying to make this work with inheritance I would stongly consider reading about templates. Templates are really simple to implement and for this code all you really need is one line of code `template <unsigned int N>` before `class Vector` to get ridd of the `Vector2,Vector3,...` classes:

```
template<unsigned int N>
class Vector{
   private:
     double x[N]; // Components of a general N-dim vector
   ...

   // Example of how to write a general function. You can use N
   // as a normal integer within the class
   void normalize(){
      double norm = 0.0;
      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        norm += x[i]*x[i];
      }
      norm = 1.0/sqrt(norm);
      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        x[i] *= norm;
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

You would then create a 2D vector by simply writing `Vector<2> v;`. This also gets ridd of *all* the code duplication you now have!  As a bonus it will work for all `N` and you can also template over the type with little change to the code and get a vector that works with other types like `float` for free.

---

Some comments on your code:

As of now you have nothing useful in the base-class except for virtual function definitions and `static const double pi` so this class is not really neeed at all - it just adds unnessesary code. Also `pi` is not really part of a vector so it does not belong in the class. If you really need `pi` as a constant [get it from the math library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c).

Instead of having the component separate as `double x, y, z, ...` I would use an array here `double x[N]`. If you do this then you can then replace the functions `getX,getY,getZ` with a single function

```
double getCoordinate(unsigned int i){
    if( i < N ) { 
       return x[i];
    } else {
       // Raise error, this is not a valid coordinate
       // ...
    }
}
```

Likewise you can replace `setX,setY,setZ` with `setCoordinate(unsigned int i)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Oh yeah I'm about to read up on templates, it's the next chapter of my book. I just wanted to apply my inheritance knowledge practically before I moved on. As for the redundancy of the base-class, what if I had some program that wanted to deal with a general vector without need to worry about its dimension. Would this not warrant the use of a base class so I could refer to any `n`-dimension vector object in this general sense (even if there was barely any code inside `Vector`)?

Comment: @AntiElephant Yes, I agree it's not completely redundant, but I don't think that its enough to warrant using inheritance here unless you want to do something crazy like adding a 2D and 3D vector:) But that is not how vectors are normally used so I would not worry about it in a general vector class. Note that one can also make a function that takes a general vector by using templates. E.g. if `foo` is some function that takes in a general vector then you can simply write `template<int N> void foo(Vector<N> v){ ... }` and the function will work on all vectors.

Answer (score 1):

[Winther](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108079/31292) covers most of the important features. I just want to throw out a minor one. You currently have `set*` and `get*` functions. But much more typically used in C++ containers are `operator[]` and `at()`. The former doing zero range checking and the latter potentially throwing. I would suggest you do the same:

```
// no range checking
double& operator[](size_t idx) { return _data[idx]; }
const double& operator[](size_t idx) const { return _data[idx]; }

double& at(size_t idx) {
    if (idx >= N) throw std::out_of_range(...);
    return (*this)[idx];
}

const double& at(size_t idx) const {
    if (idx >= N) throw std::out_of_range(...);
    return (*this)[idx];
}
```

It's just more natural to write `vec[0] = 4` than `vec.setX(4)` or `vec.setCoordinate(0, 4)`.

Similarly, `get_length()` should be called either `length()` or `size()`.

---

For normalization, I would also seriously consider this signature:

```
Vector normalize() const;
```

It will make code easier to reason about. Furthermore, this doesn't even need to be a member function:

```
template <size_t N>
Vector<N> normalized(Vector<N> const& );
```